# How to print COCOeval results to file, or get the printed str?

Tags: python

Following the [coco api toturial](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocoEvalDemo.ipynb), using `cocoEval.evaluate()`, `cocoEval.accumulate()` and `cocoEval.summarize()` can have the ecaluation result printed in the console.

I wonder if there is a way one can derive the `str` object of evaluation result, rather than have it printed, so that I can record it to my history file. Better if no need to modify the original code in cocoapi. I'm not sure if cocoapi has some relative interfaces.

I've checked the source code in `COCOeval` and found it's possible if I make `cocoEval.evaluate()`, `cocoEval.accumulate()` and `cocoEval.summarize()` return the `str`s. But these methods do return something else. I'm afraid there will be some potential instability after changing or extending their original return value, since some other functions may need them.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing all this, you can actually do redirection. In your terminal you can run your script and redirect the output to a file. The output of the console will be logged to a file.

E.g. `python eval_model.py > results.txt`

Answer (score 1):

The results have also been saved to `stats`, more specifically, you can directly use `cocoEval.stats` to extract the mAP results.